# Laravel: Can't see 404 if route/url entered manually

Tags: php, laravel

Building a laravel app (Blog/posts).
While viewing any particular post(via slug), the url is like this

```
http://localhost:8000/post/corporate-world-1
```

So if some puts any random slug,

```
http://localhost:8000/post/jajdajkjknjfna
```

it is not showing 404, instead it is like:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'post_image' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blogsnposts\resources\views\post\show.blade.php)
```

Comment: Show us the controller and the `show.blade.php` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not handling the 404 in your controller. Without seeing the controller's code, I can only assume that the controller tries to fetch a content from the database with a non-existing slug, returns null but then you still pass the object fetched from the database to the view. You need to test if the objects exists and return a 404 if it doesn't. It would look something like this

```
function post($slug) { 
       $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
       // This is probably missing
       if (!$post) {
           abort(404);
       }
       return view('show', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

Comment: Really Thanks alot! As am a newbie, was missing out this silly thing!

Comment: You will need the exact same code to the edit page so you should go for the middleware solution to avoid repeating code. @RaviWadhwani

Comment: Okay. Thanks alot @Tiago_nes I'll keep your suggestion in mind & will make use of middlewares :)

Comment: Done! @Tiago_nes

Answer (score 0):

You can add a middleware to the route.

```
Route::get('post/{post}', PostController@show)->middleware('checkPost');
```

in kernel.php

```
'checkPost' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\CheckPostMiddleware::class,
```

In the middleware you check if the url contains a valid post else

```
return abort(404);
```